# "Pieces of equipment" vs. "equipment pieces"

Tags: adjuncts

In the sentence: The detonator for a nuclear device may be made of_____:

A) two pieces of equipment
B) two equipment pieces

I strongly feel that the correct option is A. But why? When should I use of; and when should I omit it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this is just a case of learning the different sorts of usage. There's nothing analytically **wrong** with *equipment pieces*, much as we can say "slice of cake" or "cake slice". We just **don't** say *equipment piece(s)*. It's always *piece(s) of equipment*.

Answer (score 1):

"pieces of equipment" (red line) vs "equipment pieces" (blue line) - [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=equipment%20pieces%2Cpieces%20of%20equipment&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cequipment%20pieces%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpieces%20of%20equipment%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

two pieces of equipment
two pieces of furniture
two pieces of art
a fine piece of wisdom

With some uncountable nouns, "of" is used. That's just the way it is.

Comment: There was no need to edit this.

Comment: As you intended, [you originally wrote it as a list](https://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/d7ca6cd9-b9eb-4471-a7cc-299fbcbffd93/view-source), and it was easier to read the examples in a list. Now this stream of words has not a single comma, no punctuation whatsoever, it doesn't look good.

Comment: Yes, I originally wrote it as a list and when I arrived back at the page, I saw that it said you had edited it but in fact it was still **just the list on the edit page**. I have no idea why it reverted to a form which was not the one I had originally. But now I have put it back into a list form. This site drives me crazy sometimes.

Comment: You need to add double space every time you want to start a new line. It's in the edit comment I left you. ;)

Comment: I don't get it. My answer was **already a list**. So why edit it? I know how to do a list. Two spaces after the punctuation mark. You are not paying attention to what I'm saying. I checked my answer after I posted it and **It was a list**.

Comment: No, it wasn't a list when it was *submitted*. When you were composing it seemed like a list but ask yourself, why would I bother editing? I don't do trivial edits, very rarely, the edit I made was fixing the formatting. I can assure you that the expressions were lined up without any commas. I can't force you to believe me but it's the truth. In fact when you rolled back the edit, what happened? [**It wasn't a list**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/318749/1).

Comment: OK, I am just saying that I checked the answer and it did look like a list.

Comment: Although "art piece" is [a phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_of_art), as is [timepiece](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/timepiece) so there's not much logic at work here.

Comment: @StuartF Yes, you can say art piece but people also say piece of art or piece of cake or piece of you-know-what. :)

Comment: Museum-goers observe a painting at the National Gallery of Art. How can art lovers find the essential pieces of art in a city filled with classics? (Lisa Corson/Gallerystock.)